# Objective-C - NSXML reading new line where I won't

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, nsxmlparser

My question is pretty simple. I'm parsing an XML and the parsing procedure went pretty good with NSXML. I put all the voices in some arrays and now I'm composing a string with that. My problem is that if I write the XML in this way...

```
<main>
  <introductions>
    <text>Text 01</text> 
    <text>Text 02</text>
  </introductions>
</main>
```

... and I append the 2 strings in a label on the storyboard I obtain:

```
Text 01
Text 02
```

I was trying to figure out where that new line came from, so I tried some things and I discovered that this XML...

```
<main>
  <introductions>
    <text>Text 01</text> <text>Text 02</text>
  </introductions>
</main>
```

... produces...

```
Text 01 Text 02
```

Why this? Why the NSXML is reading what's outside the tags? How can I avoid this?

If it can helps, that's how I initialize the parser:

```
 NSURL *xml = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"frasi" ofType:@"xml"]];
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:xml]];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
[xmlParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
[xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[xmlParser parse];
```

And this is the rest of the code (for my real XML):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    currentElement = [elementName copy];

    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"introduzioni"] || [currentElement isEqualToString:@"soggetti"]
        || [currentElement isEqualToString:@"verbi"] || [currentElement isEqualToString:@"luoghi"]){
        ++depth;
        //[self showCurrentDepth];
        NSLog(@"Sezione %@", elementName);
        sezione = [[NSString alloc] init];
        sezione = currentElement;
    }
    else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"testo"]){
        currentName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"introduzioni"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"soggetti"]
        || [elementName isEqualToString:@"verbi"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"luoghi"]){
        --depth;
        //[self showCurrentDepth];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"testo"]){
        if (depth == 1){
          NSLog(@"Testo: %@", currentName);
            if([sezione isEqualToString:@"introduzioni"])
                [arrayIntroduzioni addObject:currentName];
            if([sezione isEqualToString:@"soggetti"])
                [arraySoggetti addObject:currentName];
            if([sezione isEqualToString:@"verbi"])
                [arrayVerbi addObject:currentName];
            if([sezione isEqualToString:@"luoghi"])
                [arrayLuoghi addObject:currentName];
        }
    }
}        

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"testo"]){
        [currentName appendString:string];
    } 
}
```

---

Comment: show us some code. How you add the text values and how you read them

Comment: @Lefteris: It's quite hard, because it's a lot of code and that XML is just a sample made ad hoc for my problem. I'd have to change all the code again for fit it. I can assure you that the parsing is ok. I just append the strings using "stringAppendByString" and the behavior changes as I change the XML, while I expected not. That's the problem... By the way, I'll try to add some pieces of code that might help you.

Comment: Alberto you can guess it's even harder for us to help you without the code. Just show us the pieces of the code, not the entire code

Comment: @Lefteris Indeed, as I said, I added some pieces. Tell me if you need more. And thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems that I fixed it using "stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet", but I'm still interested in understanding that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate method `parser:foundCharacters:` will deliver all character data, i.e. the data your looking for as well as all the whitespace between tags.

When the whitespace between the first closing `</text>` and the second opening `<text>` is received, the variable `currentElement` still contains `"testo"`. So you append the whitespace (a line break) to `currentName` even though the parser is outside the tag you're interested in.

In order to fix it, you will either need a better handling for `currentElement` (such as setting it to `nil` after each ending tag) or you'll need to additionally check the stack depth.

Comment: Thanks. Just another question so... How do I set 'currentElement' to 'nil' after each ending tag?

Comment: @AlbertoSchiariti: Simply put `currentElement = nil;` somewhere into `parser:didEndElement:`.